# What does the number mean in Sylgard 170, Sylgard 184, etc?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, polymers, organosilicon-compounds

My lab uses a lot of [PDMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydimethylsiloxane), a silicon-based organic polymer, to make microfluidic devices. PDMS is available in many different formulations, and we usually use Dow Corning's [Sylgard 184](http://www.dowcorning.com/applications/search/default.aspx?R=131EN). Recently we got a batch of Sylgard 170 (which is supposed to cure to a solid much faster than 184), and apparently there's a whole bunch of different Sylgard types with numbers ranging from 160 to 577.

My question is, what does that number in the name of each different Sylgard type mean?

I can't seem to find a clear answer online. I know it's not directly related to curing speed, since 182 cures slower than 184. My guess is that it refers to the number of monomer residues in the polymer. Does anyone actually know?

Comment: Perhaps molecular weight?